# High validation accuracy and training accuracy but low test accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, lstm, keras

I have a LSTM model that has good training accuracy(~90%) and excellent validation accuracy(> 95%) but it gives poor results when I test it on data it hasn't seen. I am training hyperparameters using my validation set.
I don't imagine it is an overfitting problem because in that case my validation loss would be high but it isn't. I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Are you training hyperparameters by using your validation set?

Comment: Yes i am training hyperparameters using validation set

Comment: Please include that critical information in your question.

Comment: Just did. Thanks!